# Change Numpy savetxt from using datatype int16 to int8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I use `savetxt` in numpy to store text files containing binary values as the following:

```
np.savetxt(filepath, Arr, fmt='%d')
```

I realized that `fmt='%d'` uses `int16` datatype (which is 2 bytes for each value) even if `Arr` is created as `np.int8`. For instance:

```
def convert_size(size_bytes):
    if size_bytes == 0:
        return "0B"
    size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
    i = int(math.floor(math.log(size_bytes, 1024)))
    p = math.pow(1024, i)
    s = round(size_bytes // p, 2)
    return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[I])

n = 1000
dim = 64
Arr = np.random.choice(np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.int8), size=(n, dim))
Arr = np.unique(Arr, axis=0)
print(convert_size(Arr.nbytes))
filepath = open('test.txt', 'w')
np.savetxt(filepath, Arr.astype(np.int8), fmt='%d')
filepath.close()
```

yields to `test.txt` of size 128 KB while I am expecting 64 KB. Since my values to be written are binary, and very very large, I want to save the size of the file by using `int8` instead, how can I force `np.savetxt` to use `int8`?

Thank you

Comment: downvote? If the answer is trivial, I really don't see it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seriously misunderstanding the format `numpy.savetxt` uses. It's not int16 or int8 or anything like that. It's **text**. That's why it says `txt`.

You're spending two bytes per number because

```
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

takes two bytes per number, one for the digit and one for the separating whitespace. It would take more bytes if your numbers had more decimal digits.

If you want to save your array in binary format, consider `numpy.save`.

Comment: Ouch! I totally misunderstood that. thank you so much